# Definitely hide Chrome extensions warnings

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-extension

I've been a React.js developer for a while, and until now, I've always ignored the warnings in development mode caused by my Chrome extensions.
However, today I decided to search for answers on how to definitely hide them, and the closest answer I could find was from Stack Exchange: https://superuser.com/questions/357354/chrome-hide-extension-errors-in-javascript-console/870453
(question from 8 years ago, latest answer from 2 years ago).

No answer permanently solves the issue, so I was wondering if someone's found a solution since then. Maybe something from a VSCode extension? A Chrome extension?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no permission related to this. So in chrome to do, you need to modify its source. So the closet thing you can achieve is build a custom browser than add permission to enable or disable or modify console. Another a big try catch block - and no error encounter, I guess 

Comment: You can hide anything shown in console by using a filter in its toolbar.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is it persistent if you close and re-open the console though?

Comment: Of course. It shouldn't take more than a couple of seconds to verify though...